# C programming Problem - Maximum Partitions

Tags: c, algorithm, permutation, software-design

I'm struggling to solve and implement in C a function that gets as input
a "string" which it contains the chars 'a' or 'b' (the input string might be included chars 'a' and 'b' altogether) , and what the function does is to
divide the string to three parts each permutation/set without having NULL/empty chars at each permutation/set. the length of the
permutation/set isn't necessarily equal, but they all (all the three parts of each set/permutation) have the same
number of occurrence/appearance of chars 'a' .
the function must return the maximum possibilities that we can divide the string by 3 at each possible set/permutation.

Examples:
#1
input string: "ababa" is having 4 possibilities of permutations/sets (as I said each permutations is contains from 3 parts and if there's no 3 parts so this possibility is discarded ! ), in this case the maximum possibilities are:
(ab,a,ba) , (a,bab,a) , (a,ba,ba) ,(ab,ab,a).

#2
input string: "bbbbb" is having 6 possibilities of permutations/sets (as I said each permutations is contains from 3 parts and if there's no 3 parts so this possibility is discarded ! ), in this case the maximum possibilities are: (be careful here 'a' is o has no occurance so at each permutation/set there's no 'a' and it's equal for each set -has no 'a'-)
(bb,b,bb) , (bbb,b,b) , (bb,bb,b) ,(b,bbb,b),(b,bb,bb),(b,b,bbb).

#3
input string:'ababb' is having 0 possibilities, so the function returns empty string or NULL or " " even could return whatever we want which resemble about there's no possibilities for this string.

Im struggling to implement this function in C and Im stuck on it about three days.
I started to think to solve this problem in recursive approach because we are talking about permutations and maximum possibilities.
so I deeply thought and started with my algorithm as this:
first condition is to check :
'a' % 3 == 0 for every 3 parts of one permutation/set . (set consists 3 parts )
and then to think what's the recursive rule for the other condition (the length of string > 3).
but Im stuck and I couldn't complete I don't know how to continue, any help please? the hardest thing is to discover the recursive rule for my problem with its edge conditions.

Any help out?!

thanks alot.

Comment: These things are not called permutations but partitions. The word "permutation" is reserved for something else.

Comment: Do you want to output the number of possibilities only, or to print the different partitions?

Comment: @Damien to print all the different possible sets-partitions. (every possibility has a set of 3 partitions as far as  it possible to be partitioned)

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. sorry for that , missed it up .. so it's partitions .

Answer (score 3):

With fixed number of parts and known number `K` of `"a"`'s in every part you need just:

find position of `K`-th "a"  `p1`
find position of `K+1`-st "a"  `p2`
find position of `2K`-th "a"   `p3`
find position of `2K+1`-st "a"  `p4`

Then make two for-loops - one (`i` index) goes from `p1` position to `p2-1`, second (`j` index) goes from `p3` position to `p4-1`, and output string parts limited by `[0..i], [i+1..j], [j+1..strlen-1]` indices.

Example in Python:

```
def makeparts(s):
    acnt = s.count('a')
    if acnt % 3:
        return #no solutions
    ca = 0
    ka = acnt // 3
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] == 'a':
            ca += 1
            if ca == ka:
                ip1 = i
            elif ca == ka + 1:
                ip2 = i
            if ca == 2 * ka:  #note separate "if"
                ip3 = i
            elif ca == 2 * ka + 1:
                ip4 = i
    for left in range(ip1, ip2):
        for right in range(ip3, ip4):
            print(s[:left + 1], s[left+1:right+1], s[right+1:])

makeparts('abbabbba')
makeparts('abbababbbababa')

a bba bbba
a bbab bba
a bbabb ba
a bbabbb a
ab ba bbba
ab bab bba
ab babb ba
ab babbb a
abb a bbba
abb ab bba
abb abb ba
abb abbb a

abba babbba baba
abba babbbab aba
abbab abbba baba
abbab abbbab aba
```

Comment: Appreciate your reply, but didn't understand you well. may you explain it by an example or even a code in any language you want (python / matlab / java .. whatever ) to understand you well .. doesn't matter for me which language would you code because I want to understand the concept. thanks in advance

Comment: a pseudo code for demonstrating the concept / idea would also be good for me to understand well. if I take the approach of recursive apparoch then the part of the recursive rule is really the hardest part for me to understand  / to implement it.

Comment: @Ryan OK, look at Python implementation

Comment: thanks alot, but I still confused the concept of your algorithm. why I need K+1 and 2k , 2k+1 positions? not clearing for me why I need to find the K and K+1 , 2k , 2k+1 positions? why for instance not k , k+1 , 3k , 3k+1 ....could you please explain in words the algorithm (exactly the part of finding the Kth positions and 2kth positions)

Comment: Whole string contains 3K of "a"'s, so the first part should contain K "a"'s, the second part should K "a"'s numbered from K+1 to 2K, the third part should contain K "a"'s numbered from 2K+1 to 3K. Is it clear?

Comment: Yes, but what's K? is it number of 'a' per part? in other words equal to 3? if so then the indexes of k , 2k+1 , 3k is not compatible ..

Comment: Yes, K is number of 'a' per part - this is written in the first sentence of answer. So overall number of 'a' is **3K**.  `k , 2k+1` aren't indexes in string, they are numbers of 'a' upto current (i-th) position

Comment: I still confused, lets assume I have input "abbabba" . we need at every part K to be equal to the each of the other part ..so here in my case how K applied to my example? is it equal to 1?

Comment: Yes. K is 1 here

Answer (score 1):

To get three parts, you have to do 2 splits. One can determine in advance between which occurrences of "a" these splits have to be. Each split has to be done in a (possibly empty) sequence of "b"s. If the are n "b"s at the split position there are n+1 possible cuts. Just combine all possibilities for the first split with all possibilities for the second split.

Comment: Yes, I need to split it twice (by 2) . but Im stuck on the recursive rule and it's the hardest part for me , three days just stuck on this ! , may you explain more by any pseudo code or whatever? would be more appreciated .

Comment: There is no recursion necessary. Just use two nested for loops. One for the first split position, the other for the second split position.

Comment: Yes , apparently my recursive approach makes problem more complex so wouldn't go to this approach. according to what you claimed, so lets assume I have string with length 5 so two for loops on it and they iterate till length 5? I didn't honestly understand how two loops are solving the problem. could you elaborate that by pseudo code? just for understand what you mean.